# How to edit existing rolebinding in Openshift using yml files?

Tags: openshift

I have a predefined rolebinding in place for an Openshift project, that I want to edit/update using a .yml file.

I have already tried the below:

- `oc create –f` –> failed, obvious because it exists, the error is:

  ```
  Error from server: rolebinding "edit" already exists
  ```
- `oc patch –f`–> failed, looks like patch only accepts –p argument, the error is:

  ```
  Error: Must specify -p to patch
  See 'oc patch -h' for help and examples.
  ```
- `oc replace –f`–> failed, the error is:

  ```
  Error: error when replacing "sample.yml": resource name may not be empty
  If I were to run the create command against the file on a new project, it works.
  ```

Please do respond if any one has thoughts on this.

Thanks much,
Aneesh

Comment: Any reason you can't just work out way of doing it with ``oc patch``? It would also be helpful to see the yaml you are using so can understand better what you are doing and do tests with it so can suggest solution.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton .. lemme try to attach the yml files.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: Here you go .. [defaultpolicy.yml] `apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  groupNames:
  - group-name-a
  - group-name-b
  kind: RoleBinding
  metadata:
    name: edit
    namespace: project-name-a
  roleRef:
    name: edit
    namespace: project-name-a
  subjects:
  - kind: Group
    name: group-name-a
  - kind: Group
    name: group-name-b
  userNames: null
`

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton ..  [additionalpolicy.yml] `apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  groupNames:
  - group-name-x
  - group-name-y
  - group-name-z
  kind: RoleBinding
  metadata:
    name: edit
    namespace: project-name-a
  roleRef:
    name: edit
    namespace: project-name-a
  subjects:
  - kind: Group
    name: group-name-x
  - kind: Group
    name: group-name-y
  - kind: Group
    name: group-name-z
  userNames: null
`

Comment: Tough luck attaching the files from my current network, sorry about that.

Comment: Why are you using a ``Template`` when there is no parametrisation occurring?

Comment: I ran into some issue at that point and now I can't remember why, if you think that could be a potential issue, I can try it without it being a template yml file.

Comment: Can you provide the ``oc adm policy`` commands you would use to do whatever it is you are wanting to do, or provide a reference to documentation explaining what you are trying to do. In other words, explain what want to do, rather than ask why your perceived solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `oc patch -p $(cat file.patch) ...` would work for you?

Comment: No. The format need to the patch command is quite different. You cannot just give it a resources file the same as you would use for ``oc create``, ``oc replace`` or ``oc apply``.

Comment: Agreeing with Graham, it would have been intuitive to have the option to supply a file against patch, but looks like patch only accepts a json string value; opposed to how you can pass a file to create, replace or apply.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I would use separate `oc adm policy` commands to do it.

```
oc adm policy add-role-to-group edit group-name-a
oc adm policy add-role-to-group edit group-name-b

oc adm policy add-role-to-group edit group-name-x
oc adm policy add-role-to-group edit group-name-y
oc adm policy add-role-to-group edit group-name-z
```

Using `oc patch` is only going to work if there existed a resource object for the `roleRef` name already, it isn't going to create the whole role binding object if it doesn't exist.

Modifying roles is one of the times where you can't make additive changes by simply loading a new resource object definition.

You can see this by enabling logging for the `oc` command and looking at what it does. In the case of adding additional role bindings, it will first query the existing role binding and add the change to it and then load the new modified entry with all role bindings in it.

Run:

```
oc --loglevel=9 adm policy add-role-to-group edit group-name-x
```

when only `group-name-a` and `group-name-b` have already been set up to see what I mean.